# what is use cases of F# explicit type parameters?

Tags: f#, type-parameter

As I know, explicit type parameters in value definitions is a one way to overcome "value restriction" problem.
Is there another cases when I need to use them?

**Upd**: I mean "explicitly generic constructs", where type parameter is enclosed in angle brackets, i.e.

```
let f<'T> x = x
```

Comment: Just to be clear, do you mean type parameters (at the definition), or type arguments (at the point of use)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would likely be rare, but when you want to prevent further generalization (§14.6.7):

> Explicit type parameter definitions on value and member definitions can affect the process of type inference and generalization. In particular, a declaration that includes explicit generic parameters will not be generalized beyond those generic parameters. For example, consider this function:

```
let f<'T> (x : 'T) y = x
```

> During type inference, this will result in a function of the following type, where '_b is a type inference variable that is yet to be resolved.

```
f<'T> : 'T -> '_b -> '_b
```

> To permit generalization at these definitions, either remove the explicit generic parameters (if they can be inferred), or use the required number of parameters, as the following example shows:

```
let throw<'T,'U> (x:'T) (y:'U) = x
```

Of course, you could also accomplish this with type annotations.

Answer (score 5):

Polymorphic recursion is another case.  That is, if you want to use a different generic instantiation within the function body, then you need to use explicit parameters on the definition:

```
// perfectly balanced tree
type 'a PerfectTree = 
| Single of 'a
| Node of ('a*'a) PerfectTree

// need type parameters here
let rec fold<'a,'b> (f:'a -> 'b) (g:'b->'b->'b) : 'a PerfectTree -> 'b = function
| Single a -> f a
| Node t -> t |> fold (fun (a,b) -> g (f a) (f b)) g

let sum = fold id (+)

let ten = sum (Node(Node(Single((1,2),(3,4)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Most obvious example: write a function to calculate the length of a string.

You have to write:

```
let f (a:string) = a.Length
```

and you need the annotation.  Without the annotation, the compiler can't determine the type of `a`.  Other similar examples exist - particularly when using libraries designed to be used from C#.

**Dealing with updated answer:**

The same problem applies - `string` becomes `A<string>` which has a method `get` that returns a `string`

```
let f (a:A<string>) = a.get().Length
```

Comment: please see update; question is about type arguments (not type annotations)