# How can this phantom type example possibly be valid?

Tags: haskell, types, phantom-types

```
data Expr a
  = C a
  | Add (Int -> a) (Expr Int) (Expr Int)
  | Eq (Bool -> a) (Expr Int) (Expr Int)

add = Add id
eq  = Eq id

eval :: Expr a -> a
eval (C x) = x
eval (Add f e1 e2) = f (eval e1 + eval e2)
eval (Eq f e1 e2)  = f (eval e1 == eval e2)

expr1 = (C 5 `add` C 1) `eq` C 6

main = print $ eval expr1
```

Coming from a different functional language, ever so often I get an inkling that I do not exactly get Haskell's type system and the above is one of those cases.

What the above does is emulate a GADT with phantom types, but not in a way I could have imagined it working. `Int -> a` and `Bool -> a` are supposedly proofs of what type is supposed to be here, but when I translated the above example in F# as expected, it did not work because one of the pattern matching branches returns a `bool` while the other returns an `int`.

Can anyone illuminate as to why this example is correct in Haskell?

Edit: Here is a further elaboration of the problem.

```
data Expr a
  = C a
  | Add (Expr Int) (Expr Int)
  | Eq (Expr Int) (Expr Int)

add = Add
eq  = Eq

eval :: Expr a -> a
eval (C x) = x
eval (Add e1 e2) = eval e1 + eval e2
eval (Eq e1 e2)  = eval e1 == eval e2

expr1 = (C 5 `add` C 1) `eq` C 6

main = print $ eval expr1
```

When I remove the `Int -> a` and `Bool -> a` parts, the example fails to typecheck.

But in the first example those functions can only be `id`, that is of type `Int -> Int` and `Bool -> Bool` respectively. Applying the proof function the ADTs are carrying around with them should do absolutely nothing to change that fact as they are `id` in the example and should logically fail to typecheck. Applying them should do absolutely nothing.

This is what I do not understand; as far as I am concerned this example is pretty much magical to me in terms of how types work.

Edit2: Here is the F# translation:

```
type Expr<'a> =
    | C of 'a
    | Add of ((int -> 'a) * Expr<int> * Expr<int>)
    | Eq of ((bool -> 'a) * Expr<int> * Expr<int>)

let inline id x = x
let inline add x y = Add(id,x,y)
let inline eq x y = Eq(id,x,y)

let rec eval (x: Expr<'a>) : 'a = 
    match x with
    | C x -> x
    | Add(f,x,y) -> f (eval x + eval y)
    | Eq(f,x,y) -> f (eval x = eval y)

let expr = add (C 5) (C 1) |> eq (C 7)

let r = eval expr
```

In the above example, in the `eval` function `'a` is inferred to be of type `int` and as a result the last line fails to type check.

Comment: All branches return an `a`. Maybe your translation was wrong?

Comment: No, not really. The way I read it, one returns an `Int` and the other `Bool`.

Comment: "can only be id" is wrong. Try evaluating e.g. `Add (+100) (C 1) (C 2)` of type `Expr Int` or `Add show (C 1) (C 2)` of type `Expr String`.

Comment: But `add` returns an `Expr Int` while `eq` returns an `Expr Bool`. So if you were to call `eval` on the result of `add`, then `a` will be `Int`, and it's fine to return an `Int` then.

Comment: Could you post your translation? That seems to be where the problem is. You know `Int->a` is just a function from `Int` to `a` right?

Comment: @ReidBarton As per request, I've added the Fsharp translation. In Fsharp the fields are tuples, but that is the only difference.

Comment: Does F# not allow polymorphic recursion?

Comment: The closest that I've found is [this example](http://www.fpish.net/topic/None/57593). I do not know this subject well enough to understand whether there are gradations of polymorphic recursion or how to make it work in this example.

Comment: It looks like you need to use an "explicit type parameter" `let rec eval<'a> ...` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825034/what-is-use-cases-of-f-explicit-type-parameters). Then your F# program does compile.

Comment: Holy crap, it does. I had no idea this was possible. I am glad I posted this question since I was sure this was a Haskell-only thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the following type:

```
eval :: Expr a -> a
```

This says, "given a value of type `Expr a`, for any `a` at all, I can produce an `a`". Your implementation of `eval` needs to be a proof of this statement.

Going back to the definition of the `Expr` type

```
data Expr a
  = C a
  | Add (Int -> a) (Expr Int) (Expr Int)
  | Eq (Bool -> a) (Expr Int) (Expr Int)
```

we can see that the constructors `Add` and `Eq`, apart from containing two values of type `Expr Int`, also contain a function from `Int` or `Bool` to `a`. The important part here is that *this is the same `a` as in the type constructor*, therefore the type of the value contained in this field will constrain the type of the value as a whole. You can check this in ghci:

```
λ. :t Add id
Add id :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Int
λ. :t Eq id
Eq id :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Bool
```

This also works in the other direction, meaning that if an expression of type `Expr Bool` is expected in some context, and you try to use the `Add` constructor to create this expression, the type of its first field *must* be `Int -> Bool`. Generalising this leads you to the conclusion: if an expression of type `Expr a` is expected in that context, and you attempt to create such an expression using the `Add` or `Eq` constructors, the function contained inside *must* be of type `Int -> a` or `Bool -> a`, respectively.

Therefore, the functions contained inside those constructors are *proof* that, no matter which concrete `a` is in question, you will be able to apply them to either an `Int` or a `Bool` to construct an `a`. This is true *by construction* since picking out a concrete function chooses which concrete `a` we are dealing with.

Finally, going back to the implementation of `eval`:

```
eval :: Expr a -> a
eval (C x) = x
eval (Add f e1 e2) = f (eval e1 + eval e2)
eval (Eq f e1 e2) = f (eval e1 == eval e2)
```

Let's examine the three branches to check whether it is indeed a proof of the we set out to prove, which was "given a value of type `Expr a`, for any `a` at all, I can produce an `a`":

- For the `C` branch this is trivially true since `x :: a`.
- For the `Add` branch, we can determine that the type of `eval e1 + eval e2` must be `Int`. Luckily, we have `f :: Int -> a` which, by construction, is able to give us an `a` from an `Int` so this case is proved.
- For the `Eq` branch, `eval e1 == eval e2` clearly has the type `Bool` (due to `(==)`). Again, we have `f :: Bool -> a` which is able to produce an `a` from this `Bool` and satisfy the type.

Therefore, given a value of type `Expr a` constructed via any of its constructors, we are able to produce an `a` without knowing what concrete `a` we are talking about.

Also, keep in mind that since `eval` is polymorphic in `a`, different calls of `eval` *can* return values of different types, but the above should demonstrate that for a single call, all three branches are constrained to return the same type.

Answer (score 3):

There are no phantom types here. `Expr a` is the type of expressions with a result of type `a`. It's either a given constant (`C 3`, `C "Hello"`) or a sum of integers, or an equality test of integers. Let's look at `Add`:

```
| Add (Int->a) (Expr Int) (Expr Int)
```

This takes two integers to be added and a "continuation" saying how to turn their sum into the desired result type. Similarly,

```
| Eq (Bool->a) (Expr Int) (Expr Int)
```

takes two integers to be compared and a continuation saying how to turn the result of computation them into the desired result type.

---

You can easily see that this is a functor:

```
instance Functor Expr where
  fmap f (C x) = C (f x)
  fmap f (Add g x y) = Add (f.g) x y
  fmap f (Eq g x y) = Eq (f.g) x y
```

This is reminiscent of [`Coyoneda`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.0.1/docs/Data-Functor-Coyoneda.html), but it uses `Int` instead of `f b`. It "upgrades" an expression involving `Int`s using an arbitrary function. No extra trickery is necessary.

Comment: Please see the edit. Well, obviously it works, but what I am really looking for is why that example above works in Haskell and fails in F#. The desired type of the continuations cannot possibly be `_ -> a` because the returns are different at the three branches. Also, I am not sure why you started talking about monads all of a sudden. :)

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic, I started thinking about the (instructive) `Functor` instance, but then got carried away. See my edit.